# set default value of unordered map if key doesn't exist

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

In my program I want that the default value, if a key doesn't exist in my unordered map, is going to be `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` Instead of just 0.

my code looks like the following:

```
class Pair
{
public:
   Graph::NodeId node;
   bitset<64> bits;

   Pair(Graph::NodeId node1, double bits1)
   {
       node = node1;
       bitset<64> temp(bits1);
       bits = temp;
   }

};

bool operator==(const Pair &P1, const Pair &P2)
{
   return P1.node == P2.node && P1.bits == P2.bits;
}

template <>
struct std::hash<Pair>
{
std::size_t operator()(const Pair &pair) const noexcept
{
  std::hash<decltype(pair.node)> ihash;
  std::hash<decltype(pair.bits)> bhash;
  return ihash(pair.node) * 31 + bhash(pair.bits);
}
};

unordered_map<Pair, double> lFunction;
```

so if I want to access the element `lFunction[Pair(3,3)]` and the key doesn't exist, there should be the value `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility would be to create a tiny class for the value type:

```cpp
class dproxy {
    double value_;
public:
    dproxy(double value = std::numeric_limits<double>::max())
    : value_{value} {}
    operator double &() { return value_; }
    operator double const &() const { return value_; }
};

std::unordered_map<Pair, dproxy> lFunction;
```

A default-constructed `dproxy` will be initialized to `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`, and a dproxy will implicitly convert to a (reference to a) `double`. This can impose limitations if you're doing a lot of implicit conversions otherwise though (e.g., if you had some other function `foo` that took some other type `bar` that could be implicitly constructed from a `double`, `foo(lFunction[baz]);` would work if `lFunction` contained `double`s, but not if it contained `dproxy` objects, since an implicit conversion sequence can only use one user-defined conversion).

Comment: Rats, beat me to it :) OP please read [mre] - your code could be a lot shorter and still get the point across.

Comment: Why return the `value` by reference and not by value? `operator double () { return value; } operator double () const { return value; }`

Comment: @Jerry thank you for the answer, but I added the code to my program and changed the unordered map from <Pair, double> to <Pair, dproxy> and now if I call the map with an unknown key, I still get 0. Did I do something wrong?  And can I still add an Element like the following: lFunction[Pair(3,3)] = 5? or do I have to create an instance of dproxy?

Comment: @m6rco 1) Regarding the first question, I've edited the code above to initialize `dproxy`'s `value_` member at construction. 2) Regarding `lFunction[Pair(3,3)] = 5` question, `unordered_map`'s `operator[]` will construct a `dproxy` in-place from `5`. Check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) and [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T9Efdhbvr).

Comment: @rturrado: Thanks. Post untested code, feel like an idiot...

Comment: @JerryCoffin Hehe, no worries! The fix was minimal.

Answer (score 3):

> if I want to access the element `lFunction[Pair(3,3)]` and the key doesn't exist, there should be the value `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`.

[`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) simply does not work that way. When it needs to insert a new value for a missing key, the new value is always [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which for numeric types means `0`. There is no option to change that behavior in the `unordered_map` itself. But [@JerryCoffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72807851/65863) shows you a workaround to take advantage of that behavior so you can define your own default value.

Otherwise, the alternative is to simply not use the map's `operator[]` at all. Use its [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) and [`emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) methods instead, eg:

```
auto getFunctionValue = [&](const Pair &key)
{
    auto iter = lFunction.find(key);
    if (iter == lFunction.end()) {
        iter = lFunction.emplace(key, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()).first;
        // or simply:
        // return std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    }
    return iter->second;
};

//double d = lFunction[Pair(3,3)];
double d = getFunctionValue(Pair(3,3));
...
```

Or, if you are using C++17 or later, you can use the [`try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) method instead, eg:

```
auto getFunctionValue = [&](const Pair &key)
{
    return lFunction.try_emplace(key, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()).first->second;
};

//double d = lFunction[Pair(3,3)];
double d = getFunctionValue(Pair(3,3));
...
```